# Tomcat application crashing frequently

Tags: tomcat7, ajp

Our production env looks like this:

Tomcat 7.0.61

Apache 2.4.16
On a Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit machine.

It has 7 drives with 700GB each. A lot of unused memory.

CPU looks good and memory usage looks good too.

Sine yesterday, the application has been hanging and we had to restarted Tomcat service ~7 times.

I found this erros and wondered if someone knows what is wrong?
Because it was working fine few days ag and now we are constantly restarting tomcat :/

Tomcat server.xml

```
<Service name="Catalina">     
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" packetSize="65536"/>
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
```

catalina.log

```
Feb 26, 2016 5:04:16 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpMessage processHeader
SEVERE: Invalid message received with signature 18245 Feb 26, 2016 5:04:50 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpMessage processHeader
SEVERE: Invalid message received with signature 18245 Feb 26, 2016 5:05:27 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpMessage processHeader
SEVERE: Invalid message received with signature 18501 Feb 26, 2016 5:05:33 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
Feb 26, 2016 5:45:18 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpMessage processHeader
SEVERE: Invalid message received with signature 18245 Feb 26, 2016 5:55:34 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpMessage processHeader
SEVERE: Invalid message received with signature 18245 Feb 26, 2016 5:57:57 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpMessage processHeader
SEVERE: Invalid message received with signature 18245 Feb 26, 2016 6:06:56 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpMessage processHeader
SEVERE: Invalid message received with signature 18501 Feb 26, 2016 6:07:02 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
Feb 26, 2016 8:18:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"] Feb 26, 2016 8:18:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"] Feb 26, 2016 8:18:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Feb 26, 2016 8:18:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 9 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [Faces Servlet] Feb 26, 2016 8:18:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 9 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [Faces Servlet] Feb 26, 2016 8:18:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 90 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [jsp] Feb 26, 2016 8:18:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 90 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [jsp] Feb 26, 2016 8:18:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper unload
INFO: Waiting for 90 instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [jsp] Feb 26, 2016 8:18:48 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/da8] registered the JDBC driver [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Feb 26, 2016 8:18:48 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/da8] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 26, 2016 8:18:48 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/da8] is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation.
Feb 26, 2016 8:18:48 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/da8] is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation.
```

And also this:

```
Feb 26, 2016 8:18:49 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableInformation.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1612)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.error(Log4JLogger.java:257)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:920)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:460)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layouts.BodyLayout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsert_005f1(BodyLayout_jsp.java:228)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layouts.BodyLayout_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fsubview_005f0(BodyLayout_jsp.java:202)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layouts.BodyLayout_jsp._jspService(BodyLayout_jsp.java:106)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:656)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(TilesUtilImpl.java:101)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(TilesUtil.java:137)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doInclude(InsertTag.java:758)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:890)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:460)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layouts.ClassicLayout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsert_005f1(ClassicLayout_jsp.java:459)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layouts.ClassicLayout_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fsubview_005f1(ClassicLayout_jsp.java:433)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layouts.ClassicLayout_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005ffacet_005f1(ClassicLayout_jsp.java:402)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layouts.ClassicLayout_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(ClassicLayout_jsp.java:207)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layouts.ClassicLayout_jsp._jspService(ClassicLayout_jsp.java:106)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:415)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.dispatch(JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.java:233)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.java:219)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:352)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at mil.dla.daps.web.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.myfaces.component.html.util.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2476)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2465)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you recall if anything might have changed in the last few days in your setup?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I found sqljdbc4-4.0.jar, jdbc-1.0 and mm-mysql.jar in tomcat lib folder. Both: sqljdbc4-4.0.jar and  jdbc-1.0 are also in our app/WEb-INF/lib folder. I removed them from Tomcat/lib folder and restarted Tomcat service. COuld this be the reason?